# How is possible create GnuWin Packages?

Tags: windows, gcc

Hi guys How is possible create a packages for windows with Gcc like this `http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html` anyone have tutorial? thanks

Comment: I assume the whole thing is open source. Have you actually looked at how they are doing it?

Comment: yes i am in linux and  i want compile  with Gcc  you  have a  some tutorial for  do this package in windows like in the site  gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html  thanks

Answer (score 0):

A lot of open source can be built on Windows using MinGW-w64 GCC (e.g. from https://winlibs.com/) and if needed [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/).

When using the [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) the build process is almost the same as on Unix/Linux if the open source project in question uses build tools like `./configure` or `cmake`.

If you would consider using already prebuilt packages check out the [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) package manager `pacman`.